# Strange infinite loop in thread in c# using network sockets

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking

I made a little experiment where a server send continually a message to a client until a second client be connected. Testing with telnet, the first client receive the message continually, but when the second client connects, the client counter (`nClients`) increments in the second client thread, but not in the first one. So with a third and a fourth clients an so on. Variable `nClients` still being 1 in the first client but is incremented in the next ones.
The code:

```
 class Program
{
    volatile static int nClients = 0;
    static void clientThread(object socket)
    {

        Socket client = (Socket)socket;
        IPEndPoint ieCliente = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
        Console.WriteLine("IP: {0} port: {1}", ieCliente.Address, ieCliente.Port);

        nClients++;

        Console.WriteLine(nClients);
        using (NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(client))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
            sw.Flush();

            while (nClients < 2)
            {
                sw.WriteLine($"Waiting clients... now {nClients} connected");
                sw.Flush();
                //Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            sw.WriteLine($"{nClients} clients");
            sw.Flush();

        }
        client.Close();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int port = 31416;
        IPEndPoint ie = null;
        ie = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
        using (Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
            s.Bind(ie);
            s.Listen(5);
            Console.WriteLine($"Server listening at port: {ie.Port}");
            while (true)
            {
                Socket cliente = s.Accept();
                Thread th= new Thread(clientThread);
                th.Start(cliente);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

If I add an `Thread.Sleep()` into the loop (or even a `Console.Writeline()`) it works.
Why does the first thread not detect the change of `nClients`.

**Actualization:**
Following the feeedback recommendations, I was trying de `Interlocked.Increment()` and `Volatile.Read()` but the problem persist. My code again with these changes.

```
class Program
{
    static int nClients = 0;
    static void clientThread(object socket)
    {

        Socket client = (Socket)socket;
        IPEndPoint ieCliente = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
        Console.WriteLine("IP: {0} port: {1}", ieCliente.Address, ieCliente.Port);

        Interlocked.Increment(ref nClients);

        Console.WriteLine(Volatile.Read(ref nClients));
        using (NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(client))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
            sw.Flush();

            while (Volatile.Read(ref nClients) < 2)
            {
                sw.WriteLine($"Waiting clients... now {Volatile.Read(ref nClients)} connected");
                sw.Flush();
                //Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            sw.WriteLine($"{Volatile.Read(ref nClients)} clients");
            sw.Flush();

        }
        client.Close();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int port = 31416;
        IPEndPoint ie = null;
        ie = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
        using (Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
            s.Bind(ie);
            s.Listen(5);
            Console.WriteLine($"Server listening at port: {ie.Port}");
            while (true)
            {
                Socket cliente = s.Accept();
                Thread th = new Thread(clientThread);
                th.Start(cliente);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[And here a video showing this behavior.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/108uINSrecddCxdrMCerwN2exhWAzi7LI/view?usp=sharing) And a bonus: when I close abruptly the server, sometimes the client continue in the loop.
I think that for some reason when I close the server, Windows close the process but the threads memory is not released and continue running.

Comment: *"the problem persist"* -- Do you mean that the first client always sees the `Volatile.Read(ref nClients)` to have the value `1`, although it is incremented on another thread with `Interlocked.Increment(ref nClients)`?

Comment: Yes it is. And sometimes I  close the server and the first clients remains connected in the loop. I'll try to add a gif or link a video showing this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
 nClients++;
```

This is being executed by more than one thread simultaneously, and it is not threadsafe.

The reason why is as follows. The code is (logically) equivalent to the following:

```
int temp = nClients + 1; // [A]
nClients = temp;         // [B]
```

So lets imagine that `nClients` is 0. Thread #1 executes line [A] and thus `temp` is 1. Now imagine that before thread #1 has executed [B], thread #2 comes along and executes [A]. Thread #2's value for `temp` is also 1, because nothing has changed the value of `nClients` yet.

Now both threads continue, and they both set `nClients` to `temp`, which is 1.

Oops! An increment went missing.

That's what's happening. (Well, this is actually a gross simplification, but it's a good way to understand how it can go wrong.)

To fix it you can either put a `lock` around the incrementing code, or (simpler and more efficient) use [`Interlocked.Increment()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=net-6.0#system-threading-interlocked-increment(system-int64@)):

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref nClients);
```

Comment: But in the second thread `nClients` is incremented, and in the third. It can see with the line `Console.WriteLine(nClients);` when you have, for example, five clients, you see `nCLients` as 5 in the server's console (and in the fifth telnet console), but you continue seeing 1 in the first client (and only in the first). I use a variable volatile to do the thread safe, but I tried first with locks and the problem persisted.
If always were 1 I would understand the situation as you explain.

Comment: @Curro Did you try adding the `Interlocked.Increment()`? Also, wherever you access `nClients` elsewhere, try changing it to `Volatile.Read(ref nClients)`, which will erect a memory barrier.

Comment: Hi @Matthew, I did it but the problem persist. I'm going to edit the original message adding this modification, maybe I'm doing something wrong.